# with last exoplayer2 , in java , how do I get the metadata from a radio streaming

Tags: java, android, metadata, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

Android java. Last exoplayer2. Is it now possible to get the metadata  from a radio station stream, current title and artist playing, how, and for what kind of stream. How can I even detect if it can be done for the stream exoplayer is playing. Thanks.

Comment: What was that? Is it a question or a ........? Please improve the standard of your question by providing what you tried and what is your doubt "IN ENGLISH"

Comment: I was not able to find a way to do it with exoplayer2 but I've found in that answer a way to retrieve the metadata without exoplayer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8970548/how-to-get-metadata-of-a-streaming-online-radio . At the end, in a comment you can find a project, it works but you have to change the url of the stream or you'll get a not found error. I've made an improved version of that project so we can paste an url in a TextView and improved the error management. May be I'll post it when it's really finished.